# calculo de dias entre datas php

Tags: php

Galera estou tentando verificar qual a diferença em dias, com base em 2 datas.

Bom meu código esta assim:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime("2016-07-10");
$data_fim = new DateTime("2016-07-13");

// Resgata diferença entre as datas
$dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);
$dias = $dateInterval->d + ($dateInterval->y * 12);

echo $dias;
```

Bom se eu informo os seguintes valores:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime("2016-07-10");
$data_fim = new DateTime("2016-07-13");
```

Meu retorno e 3, até ai esta tudo ok.
Porém quando coloco:

```
$data_inicio = new DateTime("2016-07-10");
$data_fim = new DateTime("2017-08-13");
```

Meu retorno continua sendo 3, ou seja o sistema ignorou os meses e anos. Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php 
    $data_inicio = new DateTime("2016-07-10");
    $data_fim = new DateTime("2017-07-10");

    // Resgata diferença entre as datas
    $dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);
    echo $dateInterval->days;

    //365
 ?>
```

Tem diferença entre `d` e `days` você pode ver as especificações [aqui](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Valeu @Ricardo Mota, simples e direto, me ajudou muito, obrigado.

Comment: Caramba, salvou o meu dia, valeu @Ricardo Mota

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar essa função:

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2016-07-10");
$date2=date_create("2017-08-13");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%a");
?>

//Saída: 399
```

Comment: muito bom, é isso mesmo. E bem mais simples. Porém preciso que a saída seja apenas numérico. Como altero isso?

Comment: echo $diff->format("%a");